# Shuffle array except for the first three elements

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

I have an array in PHP:

```
Array (
    [0] => Red
    [1] => Green
    [2] => Blue
    [3] => Yellow       
    [4] => Purple
    [5] => Orange
    [6] => Brown )
```

I want this array to be shuffled except for the first three elements ([0][1][2] should stay on the same position). E.g.:

```
Array (
    [0] => Red
    [1] => Green
    [2] => Blue
    [3] => Brown        
    [4] => Yellow
    [5] => Purple
    [6] => Orange )
```

I know how to shuffle a whole array with `shuffle( $array );` but I need advise how to not shuffle the first three elements of that array. Thanks!

Comment: Show your effort, what problem you are facing. We are not here for doing your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is you can do:

```
$a=array("red","green","blue","yellow","brown");
$partA = array_slice($a,0,3);
$partB = array_slice($a,3,sizeof($a));
shuffle($partB);
$result = array_merge($partA, $partB);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I also don’t understand the downvote — the code works for me.

Comment: What's wrong with in-place shuffling? Correct me if I am wrong, but this looks like creation of three aux sub arrays.

Comment: @user1706680 you can accept answer if it works for you.